# How to override the method OnBackButtonPressed() to navigate back two pages or more in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to override the hardware back button to go back two pages. Of course I can not override it with the normal navigation proccess  `await  Navigation.PushAsync(new SomePage());` because it will make the method async which does not match the base method bool return type. any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2], to navigate back to two pages .